# Bad Gateway on server, but not on local using port 3000

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean, bcrypt

I recently implemented a user authorization model for my Node/Express/Angular project, using this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/

Running it on my local machine works great, but when I upload it to my digital ocean account, where I've been successfully hosting the project up till now, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. Even if I use the direct IP address and port.

I'm running thier MEAN instance on Ubuntu 14 and have other sites running on other instances.

I'm also running Nginx on that instance.

I just don't get how I can run the app locally on my "localhost:3000" but running it on the VH is giving me a connection refused.

**I've issolated the problem to being "bcrypt". For some reason it is causing the problem.**

Has anyone run  into this and any advice on debugging?

Here is what I see in my Nginx logs. As far as I know, I'm not using PHP on this server, but I see an entry there.

```
2016/12/05 02:16:47 [error] 10693#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/", host: "maybarry.com"
2016/12/05 02:16:50 [error] 10693#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/", host: "maybarry.com"
2016/12/05 02:17:11 [error] 10693#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/", host: "maybarry.com"
2016/12/05 02:28:37 [error] 10867#0: *4 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "POST /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/api/authenticate", host: "maybarry.com", referrer: "http://maybarry.com/login"
2016/12/05 02:31:42 [error] 10867#0: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/api/signup", host: "maybarry.com", referrer: "http://maybarry.com/register"
2016/12/05 10:27:48 [error] 12671#0: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/api/signup", host: "maybarry.com", referrer: "http://maybarry.com/register"
2016/12/05 10:27:48 [error] 12671#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/api/signup", host: "maybarry.com", referrer: "http://maybarry.com/register"
2016/12/05 10:40:56 [error] 12983#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET /register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/register", host: "maybarry.com"
2016/12/05 10:40:59 [error] 12983#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.108.92.101, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET /register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/register", host: "maybarry.com"
2016/12/05 10:41:48 [error] 12983#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 195.154.181.162, server: maybarry.com, request: "GET /_file-manager/php/connector.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://132.64.19.81:3000/_file-manager/php/connector.php", host: "maybarry.com", referrer: "http://maybarry.com/_file-manager/php/connector.php"
```

This is my user.js file. When I comment out the reference to bcrypt, everything works. Well, except the bcrypt methods. So I know this has something to do with it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Thanks to http://blog.matoski.com/articles/jwt-express-node-mongoose/

// set up a mongoose model
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(passw, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: There's nothing serving your application on DO, perhaps a permission issue. What's running on your local instance? You can check NGINX error logs to see why it's giving 502.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence, I added the logs that I see. I'm not sure what to make of them. Anything you see that I might check?

Comment: How do you know it's a problem with bcrypt? Can you post any code at all for us to help you with?

Comment: Okay, so from the NGINX logs we can tell that nothing is serving on port 3000. Have you started your app either directly with `node your_app.js` or via a manager such as `pm2`? If you have, and you're still receiving an error, it *might* be because you're proxying to the IP:port, so the firewall might be blocking it. Either try adding an ACCEPT rule for 3000 or change the IP in the `proxy_pass` directive in NGINX to `127.0.0.1:3000` to tell  NGINX to use the loopback interface.

Comment: @Paul, I expanded my original post to include the file that references the bcrypt. If I comment that ref  out the site connects fine.

Comment: @cnak2 Ah, I see. So if `bcrytp` is working on your local instance (I assume Ubuntu) and not on your DO instance (I assume CentOS), then it might be a SELinux issue. You can check by running the following command from the DO instance terminal (as root) `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep bcrypt`. If it returns something, then that's the issue.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence, My dev system is Mac and my server instance is on Digital Ocean's Ubuntu 14. I ran that script and got the following: root@mayberry:~# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep bcrypt
cat: /var/log/audit/audit.log: No such file or directory. Bcrypt is installed via npm on my local and should be in the project, which I upload via ssh ftp to DO.

Comment: Yeah, ignore everything that I said in the last comment. It won't apply to an Ubuntu installation. Perhaps try installing Bcrypt on the DO instance.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence, installed Bcrypt on DO and I still get the same result after restarting everything from Nginx to node.js app. Thinking of using "crypto" instead. Though I heard that bcrypt is better and would love to just figure out why that's not working on the server side. Just weird.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence i haver started my app using pm2 start 'ecosystem.config.js' but it doesn't starting thought app instance is created giving me 502 bad gatway error. What can be the issue